# issue with array duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

im trying to create a table with a specific type of object and number of occurrences in my data set. I tried to create 2 sets of arrays to first index the order type, and if the order type is already present in the first array add a 1 to an occurrences array. The issue i am getting is that each row is getting indexed as its own type and returning an occurrence of 1. Here is the code im using

```
Sub Comparison() 
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Book As Workbook
Set Book = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Set Sheet = Book.Sheets("Sheet1")
 
Dim i As Integer
Dim c As Integer 'counter for number of items needed in array
Dim arr() As String 'type of order
Dim occ() As Long
For i = 2 To 31
If Sheet.Cells(i, 3).Value <> "" And Sheet.Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then
If isThere(Sheet.Cells(i, 2).Value, arr, c) = -1 Then
c = c + 1
ReDim Preserve arr(1 To c)
arr(c) = Sheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
ReDim Preserve occ(1 To c)
occ(c) = 1
Else
occ(isThere(Sheet.Cells(i, 2).Value, arr, c)) = occ(isThere(Sheet.Cells(i, 2).Value, arr, c)) + 1
End If
End If
Next i
```

End Sub

```
Public Function isThere(search As String, arra As Variant, x As Integer) As Long
Dim q
isThere = -1
 
For q = 1 To x
If StrComp(search, arra(q), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
isThere = q
Exit For
End If
Next q
End Function
```

Comment: Fixed this because i had made a typo in the StrComp() and didn't realize it was always returning -1

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using two arrays you can use one dictionary.

Dictionaries have unique keys and a paired item value, the key will be your cell value, the item will be the occurance.

```
dim mydict as object
dim i as long
dim myval as variant

set mydict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'If you want to early bind add the reference to microsoft scripting runtime and set mydict to new dictionary

For i = 2 To 31
    myval = .cells(i, 3).value
    'check to see if the key exists
    if mydict.exists(myval) then
         mydict(myval) = mydict(myval) + 1
    else
         mydict.add myval, 1
    end if
next i
```